# Laravel: how to mix 'and' and 'or' conditions in a where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've searched and found similar posts but none of them are the same as my case. Seems the Laravel documents don't show a case like mine though my case is quite common in a where clause of database queries.

The where clause in my case is like the following and I can't get it to work with where() and orwhere() methods and tricks people suggested in other posts. Any info appreciated.  Thanks.

```
where a = 1 and b = 2 and (c = 3 or c = 4) and (d = 5 or d = 6)
```

Another level of complication is that I can combine all 'and' conditions into one single array and feed it into one where() method, but I have to group 'or' conditions into separate arrays and how many groups are dynamically collected in the codes, such as the following.

```
$and = [['a', '=', 1], ['b', '=', 2], ...];

if($cond1) $or['or1'] = [['c', '=', 3], ['c', '=', 4], ...];
if($cond2) $or['or2'] = [['d', '=', 5], ['d', '=', 6], ...];
if($cond3) $or['or3'] = [['e', '=', 7], ['e', '=', 8], ...];
...
```

PS:  I like to thank all who replied (posts or comments).  I've seriously considered all suggestions and tried some that could be applied to my case, but unfortunately none of them worked.  So my solution is just to compile a raw where clause as shown in the example I gave above and used whereRaw() method. It's straight forward to do and worked quite well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like so

```
Model::where('a', '1')
    ->where('b', '2')
    ->where(function ($q) {
         $q->where('c', '3')->orWhere('c', '4');
    })
    ->where(function ($q) {
         $q->where('d', '5')->orWhere('d', '5');
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Model::where([
    ['a', '=', 1],
    ['b', '=', 2],
    [['c', '=', 3], 'OR', ['c', '=', 4]],
    [['d', '=', 5], 'OR', ['d', '=', 6]]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This would be the most straight forward solution, but unfortunately it seems not working for me. Not sure if it's a feature in a newer version of laravel. My version is 5.7.19.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question, then this receipe is for you :

```
$result = DB::table('table')
   ->where('a', 1)
   ->where('b', 2)
   ->where(function($query) {
      $query->where('c', 3)
            ->orWhere('c', 4)
   })
   ->where(function($query) {
      $query->where('d', 5)
            ->orWhere('d', 6)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This should give me a work around solution as the number of group of 'or' conditions is not fixed,

Answer (score 1):

use `whereIn()` inside sub query. Havent checked, but I think this will work.

```
Model::where('a', '1')
        ->where('b', '2')
        ->where(function ($q) {
             $q->whereIn('c', ['3', '4']);
        })
        ->where(function ($q) {
             $q->whereIn('d', ['5', '6']);
        })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks.  As I added in my post, the number of group of 'or' conditions is not fixed, but this should give me a work around solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have improved your question. Here is how you can achieve it.

Haven’t tested. How about something like this.

```
$ands = [['a', '=', 1], ['b', '=', 2], ...];

$query = Model::query();
foreach($and as $and) {
    $query = $query->where($and);
}

if($cond1) $ors['c'] = [3, 4, ...];
if($cond2) $ors['d'] = [5, 6, ...];
if($cond3) $ors['e'] = [7, 8, ...];
...

foreach($ors as $key => $or) {
    $query = $query->where(function($q) use ($key, $or) {
        $q->whereIn($key,$or);
     });
}

$query->get();
```

Comment: the error show the parsed query like where (`0` = a and `1` = = and `2` = 1) and (`c` in (c, =))

Comment: can you check it now. I have brought some changes.